# nhibernate quote character replacing with \"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

Hi i making filter with linq nhibernate all working good but when i try filter text with quote select return nothing...

```
qr.Where(o => o.Desc.ToLower().Equals("some text")); // working
qr.Where(o => o.Desc.ToLower().Equals("some \"text\""));
// not working because nhibernate bind parameter as  'some \"text\"' but not  'some "text"'
```

Its some nhibernate bug? Or exist some option witch force nhibernate replace " with \" ?
Thanks for all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works fine for me (just tried your exact code)

What version of NH are you using?

```
var foos = session.Query<Foo>()
                  .Where(o => o.Desc.ToLower().Equals("some \"text\""))
                  .ToList();
```

Output:

```
NHibernate:
    select
        foo0_.id as id0_,
        foo0_.[Desc] as Desc2_0_
    from
        Foo foo0_
    where
        lower(foo0_.[Desc])=@p0;
    @p0 = 'some "text"' [Type: String (4000)]
```

Comment: @Thanks for response i am really sorry for disturb you its my fail my test was bad (( sorry again